# What is the current status of MonoGame's content pipeline?

Tags: monogame

I'd like to use any kind of content pipeline to handle textures and fonts (and ideally sounds) in MonoGame on my mac, but all of the information on content in MonoGame seems outdated. This website, https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/wiki/Xamarin-Studio-Content-Pipeline-Addin, seemed to be a basic content pipeline that would work, but the links to download the addin don't work.

Is there currently any way to easily handle at least textures and fonts in MonoGame on a mac?

Comment: What do you mean by handle?

Answer (score 0):

I think that monogame now has a content pipeline, but I'm not sure if it works on a mac. A quick glance seems to indicate that it only works with Visual Studio.

I do however, know that certain types of files can be loaded directly by Monogame. On each platform, at least one file type for Textures and Audio can be added without putting it through a content pipeline. I have to admit the big reason I don't know whether there is actually a working content pipeline, despite my main game development platform being monogame, is that I don't use it and instead directly load textures and audio in.

Font files have to go through a content pipeline though. I have a font .xnb file I've been tossing between projects for years now, compiled on XNA.

Now, I've only ever developed for windows, but on windows, the two file types I know for sure are able to be directly loaded without going through the pipeline are PNG for textures and .WAV for audio. I'm not sure which ones will be for mac, since the handy little table saying what is supported went missing, presumably when they actually implemented a pipeline.

Finally, if it turns out that PNG files don't work on a mac (it'll be one of the other file types), here is a class I wrote to convert System.Drawing Bitmaps to texture2Ds when I was working with dynamic textures.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

using System.Drawing; 

namespace DevSoc_Game.Wrappers
{
    public static class BitmapToTexture2d
    {
        static GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice; 

        public static void Init (GraphicsDevice device)
        {
            graphicsDevice = device; 
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts a bitmap to a texture2D. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="bitmap"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Texture2D BitmapToTexture2D (Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            //each pixel has four colour bytes, so multiply the array. 
            int bufferSize = bitmap.Width * bitmap.Height * 4;

            System.IO.MemoryStream memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bufferSize);
            bitmap.Save(memStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

            Texture2D texture = Texture2D.FromStream(graphicsDevice, memStream); 


            /*  Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(graphicsDevice, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);

            for (int xdx = 0; xdx < bitmap.Width; xdx++)
            {
                for (int ydx = 0; ydx < bitmap.Height; ydx++)
                {
                    System.Drawing.Color colour = bitmap.GetPixel(xdx, ydx);

                }
            }
            */
            memStream.Close(); 

            return texture; 
        }
    }
}
```

Ah, just as I come to finish writing this, I find (possibly the site I found originally) a site which has the file types monogame can load into natively. [Here, partway down](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/192209/from_xna_to_monogame.php?print=1)

From the looks of it, you're out of luck on sound as well, being on a mac.